# one line to return value of dict key in first dict in list that contains another key value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dicts:

```
DDD=[
  {'name': 'dog', 'port': 2020, 'id': 123},
  {'name': 'cat', 'port': 4242, 'id': 456},
  {'name': 'mouse', 'port': 3333, 'id': 789}
]
```

I'm looking for a one line python command to fetch the `'port'` value for the dict with a `'name'` value of `'mouse'`.

I realize there in practice may be multiple values and only need the value of the first one. (I know they're unique)

Something like:

```
d['port'] for d in DDD if d['name'] is 'mouse'
```

I'm happy for it to be a list and grab the first one with `[0]`.

Comment: The code you gave (`d['port'] for d in DDD where d['name'] is 'mouse'`) is already a one-liner, right? Just throw it in `[]` and make it a list comprehension. Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: @jme: Well, not quite; he spelled `if` as `where`. But otherwise, yeah.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to look things up by name repeatedly, you're probably better off building a dict that maps each name to a corresponding value (or list or set of values) so you can just write `DDDD['mouse']['port']`, which is a lot simpler (and also more efficient).

Comment: @abarnert Ah, missed that, and the use of `is` over `==`. Thanks. Also, to OP: if you're doing this sort of thing a lot, [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) might be the tool for you.

Comment: You can do one linner code like this `[each.get('port') for each in DDD if each.get('name') == 'mouse']`

Comment: @jme: Ah, I missed the `is`. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the potential IndexError you can do

```
([d['port'] for d in DDD if d['name']=='mouse'] or [None])[0]
```

This gets the first element of the list comprehension unless the list comprehension results in an empty list, in which case we get the contents of the `[None]` list following the `or` operator.

But if the real DDD is large and you want to look up lots of port numbers it's probably a Good Idea to follow abarnert's suggestion and create a dict that looks like this: {'mouse': 3333, 'dog': 2020, 'cat': 4242} because dict lookups are much more efficient than scanning through a list and dereferencing the dicts in it.

Here's how to do the conversion in older versions of Python:

```
DDDD = dict((d['name'], d['port']) for d in DDD)
```

In more modern versions you can also do it like this:

```
DDDD = {d['name']: d['port'] for d in DDD}
```

Comment: so which one is **better**? this answer or @jamylak's? They both seem pretty great however I do like seeing the `or` in there for readability. `next` feels a bit abstract.

Comment: @mogga: I _think_ my solution is a little more efficient: the `or` operator is pretty simple, whereas there's always a little bit of overhead setting up a generator. But I'd like to hear what Mr Barnert has to say on the matter.

Comment: @mogga: But (I repeat) both of these solutions will be _way_ slower than using a single dict to do the lookup. OTOH, there will be a little bit of overhead in creating that dict, but that will be comparable to doing a single scan through your list of dicts. So if you need to do multiple lookups, I urge you to try the DDDD approach.

Comment: Let me just clear some things up. `next` is not abstract at all. It was made specifically for this reason. this code is much less clear. the `or` adds to the confusion as well as that the `[0]` is very code golfy. On top of that, this code will run through the entire `DDD` every time while my code stops upon finding the first result.

Comment: @jamylak: Good point. It didn't sink into my feeble brain earlier that your generator terminates on the first result found, and only returns the default if the search fails. :) So it's certainly more efficient than the list comprehension which has to examine every dict in the list.

Comment: @PM2Ring It's all good. Your point about generator overhead applies in the case of tiny lists but for huge lists of thousands of items, the entire list would have to be checked each time and the generator could quickly terminate. And even in small cases the overhead time is negligible

Answer (score 5):

To make a small improvement on OP's own solution

```
next((d['port'] for d in DDD if d['name']=='mouse'), None)
```

This generator solution has the advantage of short circuiting over the list comprehension.
`None` is the default value if it doesn't find anything instead of raising an error, otherwise you can simply run `next` alone in a `try`/`except` and catch an error if that suits you better.

Comment: This works and probably the most pythonic however I do prefer the semantics of the answer in the comments from @pm-2ring specifically `([d['port'] for d in DDD if d['name']=='mouse'] or [None])[0]`

Comment: I can't change your personal preference in regards to code style, but keep in mind that that code traverse the entire `DDD` every time while this code will shortcircuit upon finding the first entry where the `if` condition is satisfied and return it straight away

Answer (score 2):

Answered it myself. This is working for me:

```
[d['port'] for d in DDD if d['name']=='mouse'][0]
```

Thanks to http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

However that will return an `IndexError` exception if the value is not found so this is what I'm doing at the moment which works:

```
exec "try: return [d['port'] for d in DDD if d['name']=='mouse'][0]\nexcept: return 0"
```

Comment: so that works but it will return an exception if there's no value found. extra points for returning a default value or 0 if none exists.

Comment: If the real DDD is large and you want to look up lots of port numbers it's probably a Good Idea to follow abarnert's suggestion and create a dict that looks like this: `{'mouse': 3333, 'dog': 2020, 'cat': 4242}` because dict lookups are _much_ more efficient than scanning through a list and dereferencing the dicts in it.

Comment: Try this: `([d['port'] for d in DDD if d['name']=='mouse'] or [None])[0]`. You can replace the `None` with any appropriate default value.

Comment: @PM-2Ring: that's nice.. I'll accept that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> DDD=[
...   {'name': 'dog', 'port': 2020, 'id': 123},
...   {'name': 'cat', 'port': 4242, 'id': 456},
...   {'name': 'mouse', 'port': 3333, 'id': 789}
... ]
>>> filter(lambda x: x['name']=='mouse',DDD)[0]['port']
3333
```

Comment: works although I find lambda hard to read sometimes and it still returns an IndexError exception if the value doesn't exist